# Post load scripts for Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

We successfully migrated data to an Azure Virtual Machine that contains a Postgresqldb with Azure Data Factory. We now need to run on this database some post-loading scripts, like creating views, create indexes and so on.

For a normal SQL-DB I would put the scripts into a Stored Procedure and trigger them in Azure Data Factory.

What is the best way to trigger these scripts for the PostgreSQL also from Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 0):

ADF stored proc acitivity does not support PostgresSQL , I think you should use Azure function as a workaround . You can always invoke the azure function from ADF .